# SVN(subversion) creating repository

Tags: linux, svn

First of all I have just an one day experience with svn so sorry if my question is too simple to ask. Here is my question: while I've searched on the net I realized that the following code block creates the repository for me.

```
$ sudo mkdir /home/svn
   $ cd /home/svn
   $ sudo mkdir myproject
```

**The SVN repository can be created using the following command:**

```
 $ sudo svnadmin create /home/svn/myproject
```

**And use the following commands to correct file permissions:**

```
 $ cd /home/svn
   $ sudo chown -R www-data:subversion myproject
   $ sudo chmod -R g+rws myproject
```

I'm fine with these lines except the one

```
$ sudo chown -R www-data:subversion myproject
```

According to what I learned, it changes the ownership status of `myproject` from `root` to `www-data:subversion`. However, I don't understand why it is necessary and what is `www-data`. By the way I'm using linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`www-data` is the default username of apache service in some linux distros.

In many default installations, subversion is served by `apache` server. `apache` cannot serve file which he has no access to. Therefore, you should change the ownership of the repo to `www-data`.

Comment: thanks for explanation.Here is another question.If I use the computer which has the repository'then no need to change it ,since I have no relation with http or network am i right ?

Comment: This depends on how you do the checkout. If you are using http:// protocol, this is still necessary. On the other hand if you are using file://, then it should work without changing the permissions. However subversion is meant to be centralized version control system. If you are using it locally, subversion is not your best choice. You better take a look on git or mercurial.

Comment: thanks again, I'll use it through network but now since I'm a newbie I use just my laptop.My final question is what is the differences between using file:// or http:// and when should I choose file and when http ? thanks in advance again. By the way, Could I use http even if using single pc ?

Comment: file:// is a protocol for accessing local files. http:// is used to access web server over a network. You can access local web server via http.